# Complex ajax web application, need a way to load test (possibly using Firefox)

Tags: firefox

Is there a Firefox plugin or system for testing complex ajax web applications.  It would be nice if I could script or macro some web clicks and then automatically test those clicks with more users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

This will likely cover the kinds of testing you'd like to do.

The [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) plugs right into Firefox.